# Determine if all vectors of the form $(a,b,c)$, where $b=a+c+1$ are subspaces of $\Bbb R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine if all vectors of the form $(a,b,c)$, where $b=a+c+1$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Use the theorem:
If $W$ is a set of one or more vectors from a vector space $V$, then $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if the following conditions hold

a) If **u** and **v** are vectors in $W$, then **u**+**v** is in $W$.
b) If $k$ is any scalar and **u** is any vector in W, then k **u** is in $W$.

Apparently, my textbook says it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is it because it doesn't contain a zero vector or what? Really confused.

Answer (score 2):

You want the set

$$A:=\left\{\;\;\begin{pmatrix}a\\a+c+1\\c\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^3\;\;;\;\;a,c\in\Bbb R\;\;\right\}$$

Now, if the origin belongs to $\;A\;$ then it **must be** that 
$$a=c=0\;,\;\;\text{and $\bf{also}$}\;\;\;a+c+1=0$$

Can you see now why the zero vector (the origin) cannot possibly belong to $\;A\;$ ?

Comment: I'd like to edit a, c in $R^3$ but the system won't let me.

Comment: Thanks anyway, @TomCollinge. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,2,1)$ are in this set you're trying to show is or is not a subspace. If it were a subspace, it'd be closed under addition. What happens if you add those vectors?